# File conflig on package updates

Tags: mysql, centos5, update

I have a CentOS 5.X with Kloxo panel.

It's a test enviroment but i have 2 pages there.

I noticed theres 113 packets to be update (php, kloxo, wget, openssl, and a long etc)

But when i do the command

```
yum update
```

I get a conflig with `/etc/my.cnf` file.

This is the message

> Transaction Check Error:
>
> file /etc/my.cnf from install of mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
>   conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.0.92-lxcenter.1.i386
>
> file /usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.15.0.0 from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql-libs-5.0.92-lxcenter.1.i386
>
> file /usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.15.0.0 from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql-libs-5.0.92-lxcenter.1.i386

The problem is, i dont really know what is happening here.

For me, there is 2 installs of mysql.

One is from lxcenter (kloxo) an the other one maybe was there from the beginin?

If it's that, how i can uninstall the second one and don't touch the kloxo mysql?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to uninstall the original one you have to find out the name of the package and be careful when uninstalling it. You will find out name of the packages by running:

```
rpm -qa|grep mysql
```

then once you are sure you found the right package to remove you'd have to run:

```
rpm -e <package_name>
```

You might have to run it with --no-deps option so that it doesn't mess other things up - also you might want to try the --test option which is basically dry-run and see whether everything will go fine. It looks like the kloxo mysql libs are conflicting with the ones which are already in place on the server.

Comment: there are 4 packages. mysql-libs-5.0.92-lxcenter.1
mysql-5.0.92-lxcenter.1
mysql-server-5.0.92-lxcenter.1
php-mysql-5.2.17-1
i'm prety sure is the last one. but the php-mysql anoins me, that have something to do with php install?

Comment: but if i see the error again it sais: mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with mysql-libs-5.0.92-lxcenter.1.i386 so the package name is the first one right? why is'nt listed? :(

Comment: if the package wasn't installed via rpm/yum but rather was compiled from source then you won't see it in rpm -qa output - otherwise you should and must see it there. But from what I can see is that you must remove the following package: mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386, you should just run sudo rpm --nodeps --test -e mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 and see if that goes OK, if yes then remove the "--test" bit and run it normally. That will remove the conflicting package

Comment: i gonna try tomorrow and i tell something ;) thanks